# Ubuntu 18.04 mouse issues after suspend

Tags: 18.04, mouse, suspend, power-management, lenovo

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 running on lenovo carbon yoga x1 (1st Gen).
Everything work fine most of the time, but after I put the computer to suspend and then wake it up in the am, the mouse goes a little whack:
- the left click of the mouse doesn't work. 
- the sliding lock screen for example looks like it's stuck in drag mode, I can slide up and down but not all the way, and I have to power cycle the machine to get to the login box.

Comment: Read `man pm-action` to see what steps your system goes through when you suspend/resume. If you find a fix, this is where it would go. What do `lsusb` and `sudo lshw` tell you about your mouse?

Comment: I ran both commands and read the man, I'm not sure how that helps. Happy to share the output. After suspend / hybernaite, I actaully have to reboot twice until the mouse comes back to normal work...

Comment: How am I suppose to fix this? I'm really unsure..

Comment: @waltinator happy to follow your instructions.

Answer (score 12):

Faced this problem today and this is what worked for me.

Make sure your device module is psmouse by running,

```
lsmod | grep psmouse
```

if its not, find the relavant module name.

```
$ cd /lib/systemd/system-sleep/
$ sudo vi fixtouchpad
```

then paste and save the following

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$1" = "post" ] && exec modprobe psmouse
[ "$1" = "pre" ] && exec rmmod psmouse
exit 0
```

This will reload your psmouse module after resuming. Replace 'psmouse' with your module name.

Be sure to make the script executable

```
sudo chmod +x fixtouchpad
```

Comment: Worked for my Fujitsu Lifebook running Ubuntu 18.04.3; it still hangs for a few seconds after standby - but it finally reacts to user input again without crazy behaviour! Thank's for this solution!

Comment: work for me at asus zenbook 13 on xubntu 20.04 Thanks!

Comment: This does not work with 20.04+logitech mouse on XPS13 (2019).

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar issues with 18.04 and they actually got worse since upgrading to 18.10.  I have a Logitech "unifying receiver" that has both a mouse and keyboard paired with it.  When resuming from sleep, fairly often either the mouse or the keyboard no longer work.  I don't remember suffering these issues with 17.10...

The following script fixed it for me:

```
for mod in hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid; do
   sudo rmmod $mod && sleep 3
   sudo modprobe $mod
done
```

If you create a script with this, don't forget to make it executable, eg with `chmod +x $HOME/fix_logitech.sh`

(not sure what the various modules are for but they looked like good candidates).  I used my laptop's integrated keyboard to type this.  If the approach works, I might consider @imeshU's approach to hook this into the System-D sleep/resume process.

Comment: So, did this work. As of late it says usbhid is a built in module and won't touch it. Script also doesn't seem to work on kernel 6. Won't let it be rmmod'd.