# Ubuntu 18.04 cursor larger after suspend resume

Tags: 18.04, gnome, suspend, themes, cursor

I have had this issue since I bought the laptop. It's the Dell XPS 13 9380 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I close the lid and it goes into suspend mode. I then open to see the mouse is twice as large as before. I have tried setting the mouse size using gnome, using the gnome tweaks app and restarting gnome post suspend.

I have read this ticket [Ubuntu 18.04 mouse issues after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054707/ubuntu-18-04-mouse-issues-after-suspend) with no luck.

Note the size of the cursor resets after opening the settings app or gnome tweaks app. The mouse is only larger when hovering the top menu bar, dock or dash panel.

Large cursor.
[image: Click to see large cursor image.]

Small cursor after opening settings app.
[image: Click to see small cursor image.]

Is there a command to run to service to restart that will update the shell theme? Can I force/ reload the cursor size after suspend?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> then type <kbd>r</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to reload GNOME Shell.

Comment: Thanks, JerareYoshi! That works but so does opening the settings application. Is there a command I can add post suspend?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. I don't think we can modify anything for the suspension.

Comment: Sorry. Instead of Using your suggestion every time I open the laptop. Is there a command I can add to a bash script in the /lib/systemd/system-sleep folder that will be triggered post suspend? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054707/ubuntu-18-04-mouse-issues-after-suspend

Comment: I think you can make a bash script the same way than in your example with this command inside: gnome-shell -r