# Logitech wireless mouse doesn't work after suspend

Tags: 20.04, usb, suspend, mouse, logitech

- OS `Ubuntu 20.04`
- Device `XPS-13 2019`
- Kernel `5.15.0-41-generic`

I am using a USB hub and connecting a Logitech wireless mouse to my laptop.

After an (automatic) suspend, the computer no longer recognizes the mouse (the USB device that emits the signal to the mouse).

Reconnecting the USB hub or the mouse solves the problem; but I don't prefer this as frequent connect-and-disconnect operations wear out the physical input/output terminals.

The output of `xinput --list` is:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL096D:01 06CB:CDE6 Mouse                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL096D:01 06CB:CDE6 Touchpad             id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ YICHIP Wireless Device Consumer Control   id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ YICHIP Wireless Device Mouse              id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ YICHIP Wireless Device System Control     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ YICHIP Wireless Device Consumer Control   id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

output of `lsmod | grep psmouse` **before** suspend is

```
psmouse               172032  0
```

**after** suspend is

```
psmouse               172032  0
```

The output of `dmesg --level=err` is:

```
[    0.067035] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[    0.427745] pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
[    0.430259] pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
[    0.831262] wmi: Failed to parse WDG method
[   44.117591] PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_resume+0x0/0x20 returns -5
[   44.117618] usb 3-8.5: PM: failed to resume async: error -5
[ 2644.419014] PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_resume+0x0/0x20 returns -5
[ 2644.419031] usb 3-8.5: PM: failed to resume async: error -5
[ 2813.787886] PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_resume+0x0/0x20 returns -5
[ 2813.787901] usb 3-8.5: PM: failed to resume async: error -5
[ 3980.333287] PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_resume+0x0/0x20 returns -5
[ 3980.333304] usb 3-8.5: PM: failed to resume async: error -5
[ 4658.805360] PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_resume+0x0/0x20 returns -5
[ 4658.805377] usb 3-8.5: PM: failed to resume async: error -5
[ 4700.060619] PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_resume+0x0/0x20 returns -5
[ 4700.060636] usb 3-8.5: PM: failed to resume async: error -5
[ 4766.598694] PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_resume+0x0/0x20 returns -5
[ 4766.598712] usb 3-8.5: PM: failed to resume async: error -5
[ 4827.793456] PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_resume+0x0/0x20 returns -5
[ 4827.793475] usb 3-8.5: PM: failed to resume async: error -5
```

where the last two lines gets appended everytime the computer wakes up from the suspend.

I've tried :

- [Ubuntu 18.04 mouse issues after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054707/ubuntu-18-04-mouse-issues-after-suspend)
- https://itsfoss.com/keyboard-mouse-freeze-suspend/

They did not work. This question is not a duplicate of the above because they're questions on different versions of Ubuntu.

It seems to be that this has been going for more than 10 years?

- [Keyboard not working after suspend to ram (sleep)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38797/keyboard-not-working-after-suspend-to-ram-sleep)
- https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/after-suspend-resume-cycle-keyboard-mouse-are-not-working/22110

They didn't work, and they are not duplicates because, again, they're questions on different versions of Ubuntu.

This question is different from :

- https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/fzr861/the_trackpad_in_ubuntu_2004_doesnt_work_after/ because this is not a trackpad problem.

Comment: Can you tell us what you tried from answers in [Ubuntu 18.04 mouse issues after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/q/1054707)? There are a few options there. Also, please add the output of `xinput --list` to your question or, even better, run `xinput --list`, find your mouse's `id` and then run `xinput list-props NN` where NN is the `id`. Also, please add the output of `lsmod | grep psmouse` before and after the suspend.

Comment: I tried all of them, accordingly.

Comment: @terdon `⎜   ↳ DLL096D:01 06CB:CDE6 Mouse               id=14 [slave  pointer  (2)]` I am assuming this to be the logitech mouse, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @terdon thank you for your sugestion, I added the outputs.

Comment: Hmm, so it looks like you're not using the `psmouse` module. So please tell us exactly what you did when you followed the answers from [Ubuntu 18.04 mouse issues after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/q/1054707). We need to find the right module.

Comment: @terdon ah okay, I didn't know that I wasn't using `psmouse` module. I just followed exactly what it said. create the file, copy-paste the script and changed permission

Comment: Please, please [edit] and _show us what you tried_. One of the answers you linked to, clearly states "if its not, find the relavant module name", which you don't seem to have done. This is very understandable, but it's the sort of thing we need to know. So don't tell us "I did what the answers suggested" because they suggest many things and we need to know. If you made a script using the name `psmouse`, then that won't help here apparently.

Comment: @Terdon, apparently so `psmouse` doens't work. I need a solution to this problem, and all I can say is that the links that I have mentioned didn't solve the problem...